# Bx slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

Take a look at the image, you can see that the image is not displayed correctly and I can't figure out how to fix it. 
http://imgur.com/a/d3onY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.OnderhoudBanner').bxSlider({
        pagerCustom: '#OnderhoudPagers',
        mode: 'vertical',
        auto: false,
        controls: false,
        slideWidth: 615
    });
});
</script>

<div class="OnderhoudBannerDiv">
<ul class="OnderhoudBanner">
    <li>
        <img src="images/Banner.jpg" />
     </li>
    <li><img src="images/Banner.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/Mickey.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/Banner.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/Mickey.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/Mickey.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/Mickey.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
<ul class="OnderhoudText">
    <li><p>qdmklqdjsfmjqdsfkmdfsqkmdfq</p></li>
    <li><p>mjqfdsjlmfdqsmfqdsjkqdfsjmqfdsjm</p></li>
</ul>
</div>

.OnderhoudBannerDiv {
    display: inline-table;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Some of your code isn't defined as code.

Comment: Fixed code indentation.

Comment: Fixed code indentation, I'm sorry! It's my first post...